# Why does bash parse same condition in different ways?

Tags: bash, shell

Today I run into strange bash behaviour, i made this simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

if true or ! true; then
    echo a;
else
    echo b;
fi

if true -o ! true; then
    echo a;
else
    echo b;
fi

if true || ! true; then
    echo a;
else
    echo b;
fi

if true or 
   ! true; then
    echo a;
else
    echo b;
fi

if true -o 
   ! true; then
    echo a;
else
    echo b;
fi

if true || 
   ! true; then
    echo a;
else
    echo b;
fi
```

The output is something unexpected for me:

```
a
a
a
b
b
a
```

I was prompted that cases 4 and 5 are treated like that:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ if true or; ! true; then echo a; else echo b; fi
b
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ if true -o; ! true; then echo a; else echo b; fi
b
```

This is working code, but it looks like a syntax error for me, and in the 6th case this  is it:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ if true ||; ! true; then echo a; else echo b; fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

The question is, is this behavior a bug or is it done intentionally? And if this is done on purpose, then what is the meaning of such differences?

Comment: `or` is not special syntax to bash. `true or false` is exactly the same as `true blah blah`, and `false or true` is the same as `false blah blah`, where "blah" could be any other string with no difference in behavior -- the `true` and `false` commands ignore their arguments.

Comment: Similarly, `-o` is only special to the `test` command (also known as `[`), it's not part of bash syntax as such. It too has no meaning to `true`, or `false`, or `if`, or anything else that isn't specifically honoring `test` syntax.

Comment: And it's completely normal/correct/expected that you can't double up command separators. `foo; ||` is just as wrong as `foo; ;` -- you can use `||` _or_ you can use `;` _or_ you can use `&&`, but you can't put two command separators after one command.

Comment: Anyhow -- the comments above try to correct some of the misunderstandings reflected in this question, but beyond that, I have no idea what it is you actually mean to ask.

Comment: BTW, no part of the behavior inquired about in this question is in any way bash-specific -- it all follows from the POSIX shell command language specification, which can be read at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html. See in particular the full grammar starting in section 2.10, from which the "can't combine multiple command separators without a command between each" limitation follows.

Comment: (The only exception to the "can't put two command separators after one command" rule is the newline, which _optionally_ becomes a separator equivalent to `;` if-and-only if it's present in a place that is in fact a legal place to put one; this too is part of the POSIX specification and not something specific to bash).

Comment: I love the experimentation you're doing. It's a great way to learn. I started writing an answer but it's a tough task because your question is so broad. There's so much ground to cover. I suggest reading some [guides](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) or [reference material](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) and see exactly what *is* valid, from which you can deduce what's not. Then if you have questions post *one* thing you're confused about and we can help.

Comment: (btw, the `true` command ignoring its arguments is often put to good use. For example, it's a fairly common idiom to write something like `: foo="$foo" bar="$bar"`, where `:` is another name for `true`; when the shell is run with tracing enabled via `set -x`, this will write something like `: 'foo=Value For Foo' bar=`, showing the current values of the relevant variables quoted in such a way as to make their values unambiguous).

Comment: If you focused on *just* the ones that print `b` you'd have a fantastic question. I would love to explain those two cases, but tackling all of them would require 10X the space.

Comment: Well, thank you all guys, the reason I asked this question was indeed in why there Is `b` in the output. I didn't know that `false` or `true` takes any arguments and that is why I thought that `true -o false` is the same as `true || false`. Now I checked `if $(echo a | grep -q a) -o $(echo b | grep -q a); then echo a; else echo b; fi` got my syntax error, and everything fell into place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the [overall syntax of `if` is](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07):

```
if
     list-of-commands
then
     another-list-of-commands
fi
```

If `list-of-commands` *exits* with *zero* exit status, then `another-list-of-commands` is executed. Zero exit status is also called a "success", whereas non-zero is, well, called a "failure".

The overall rule of thumb, is that the exit status of any list of commands is the exit status of the last command executed.

The ["list-of-commands"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03) can contain multiple list-of-commands "inside" and multiple commands inside. You can put whole scripts in there.

> ```
> if true or ! true; then
> ```

[`true` is a command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/true.1.html) that exits with zero exit status. The executable `true` is executed with 3 arguments - string `or`, string `!` and string `true`. The command `true` ignores arguments and exits with zero exit status.

Note that `or` is just `or` the string `or` it has no special meaning.

> ```
> if true -o ! true; then
> ```

Same as above, just second argument is the string `-o`. Once again `-o` are characters `-o`.

> ```
> if true || ! true; then
> ```

`||` is special. `||` executes the command on the right side when the command on the left side exits with non-zero exit status. The exit status of `||` is the exit status of the command **last** executed.

`true` exits with zero exit status. `||` does not execute the right side. The last command is `true` and exited with zero exit status. The exit status of the list `true || ! true` is zero.

> ```
>   if true or 
>   ! true; then
> ```

Formatting:

```
if 
   true or 
   ! true
then
```

There are two commands here.

First `true` command is executed with one argument `or`. Its exit status is ignored.

Then `true` command is executed, it exits with zero exit status. `!` ["inverts"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02_01) the exit status, so the exit status of `! true` is one.

The exit status of the list of commands `true or ; ! true` is the exit status **of the last** command executed. `! true` was last, it exited with non-zero. Execution is goes to the `else` branch.

> ```
> if true -o 
>  ! true; then
> ```

As above.

> ```
> if true || 
>  ! true; then
> ```

Empty lines or with only whitespaces and only a comment after `||` are ignored. This is exactly the same as the `if true || ! true; then` case.

```
if 
   true || 
   # yay a comment here

   # ^^ and empty lines too!
   ! true
 

then
```

> ```
> if true ||; ! true; then
> ```

The syntax is `command || command`. `;` ends a list of commands. There is no command after `||`. Thus, it's a syntax error.